# Solving chromosome mapping problem using linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, linear-programming, biology

In biology, we were given a problem in which we had to use "distances" (recombination frequency) between genes in order to create a genetic map of how genes are located relative to each other on a chromosome.

For example, say that gene A and B are 11 units apart, B and C are 7 units apart, A and D are 2 units apart, and C and D are 6 units apart. This corresponds to constraints $|A-B|=11$, $|B-C|=7$, and $|A-D|=2$. One solution would be D-A-C-B, with distances of 2, 4, and 7 between each pair.

Immediately, I thought of rewriting the given data as a system of equations. Each gene-distance pair could be written as A - B = 11, for example, where A and B represent the distance gene A and gene B are from some origin point. However, this makes the assumption that B is greater than A. What if A - B = -11? Since we were only given a few genes, I simply tested all of the $2^n$ positive/negative distance possibilities, and I picked out the right answer. But this wouldn't work at scale.

So I am wondering, how could a system |A - B| = 11, |B - C| = 7, etc, be solved efficently?

Comment: Well the constraints e.g. that $|A-B|=7$ could be rewritten as $A - B \ge 7$, $A-B \le 7$, $B-A \ge 7$, and $B-A \le 7$. So I agree with you it sounds like we have linear constraints, so perhaps linear programming might be relevant to this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming The most common algorithm for linear programming, the simplex algorithm, technically has exponential running time in the worst possible cases, but usually is much faster. But there are guaranteed polynomial time algorithms too.